# Why Apache is delivering .htaccess files

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess

I noticed my apache system is delivering .htaccess files although it shouldn't, due to:

```
# The following lines prevent .htaccess and .htpasswd files from being
# viewed by Web clients.
#
<Files ~ "^\.ht">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
</Files>
```

which is the default Apache configuration. I have numerous virtual host below that. How can I find out why Apache still delivers .htaccess files?

Background: tried adding a Directory directive to block .svn folders and while wondering about why apache doesn't block them I came across that issue: It's not blocking anything at all, not even default .htaccess

mod_authz_host is loaded in /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/authz_host.load

```
LoadModule authz_host_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_authz_host.so
```

Comment: You likely have a higher precedence section, like a `<Location>`, allowing access to the files.  Can you provide the simplest possible version of the "full" configuration, with other relevant server-wide sections and a virtualhost section?

Answer (score 1):

It should be:

```
<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

This requires mod_authz_host to be loaded with something similar to:

```
LoadModule authz_host_module    libexec/apache22/mod_authz_host.so
```

Comment: Same effect, added your code, restarted apache, it's still serving .htaccess files

Comment: Do you have mod_authz_host still loaded?

Comment: I think so. At least it is loaded insinde /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/authz_host.load
How can i verify?

Comment: Is there another Files type directive in the configuration, or in a `.htaccess` file (particularly near the data root)?

Comment: yes, in global apache2.conf there is: <Files *>
order deny,allow
deny from 118.139.162.190
deny from 146.185.239.52
</Files> Removing the whole Files directive makes blocking .htaccess files work again. What's wrong with that second Files directive?

Comment: @Hokascha The <Files> directive is likely above your <FilesMatch> directive. The earliest configuration takes precedence. Move your Files directive further down.

Comment: @NathanC no, the Files directive is below the one, that blocks .htaccess delivery

Comment: Try removing the `Order` directive from that other set.

Comment: After removing the Order directive .htaccess files are accessible again. For now, I will just remove the Files directive which blocked some hackers. Still better than having .htaccess etc. online ;-)